# 'Measure-Object' not working in windows powershell - how to do basic sums?

Tags: powershell

I have windows 7 at work. I don't know what version of powershell that I have, but it says it is from 2009. I have been using Google-Fu to find out how to do some basic math in powershell - sums, specific sums, etc, but what I am finding isn't working - I think it is because I am using a very old version of powershell.

For instance, this command works:

```
gc filename -totalcount 1000
```

This command does not work:

```
gc filename -head 1000
```

When I run:

```
gc filename Measure-Object "Column Name" -Sum
```

I get the error:

> "Get-Content: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Measure-Object'.

Can anyone help? Or point me to a resource that has older commands?

Comment: That is PowerShell 2.0 - default for Win 7

Comment: The syntax of your last command is wrong, and wouldn't work in any version of PowerShell as far as I can tell. What are you trying to measure? What's in your text file?

Comment: Where does "Column Name" come from? What do you want to calculate a sum of? Please show sample input data and the output you expect from that input.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the pipeline to pass one object to another command:

```
Get-Content filename | Measure-Object
```

I'd also recommend reading the documentation on [Measure-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object) so you know how to use it correctly.

Comment: What's the reference to "Column Name"? Suspect OP needs something more?

Comment: `"Column Name"` would be passed to the property param, but without knowing the content of the file I cannot say if it will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

Find your PowerShell version using this code snippet.  As noted above, 2.0 is the default for Windows 7.

```
    $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
```

Secondly, I highly recommend (unless you have specific version constraints) to upgrade to PowerShell 5.1 as there were some bugs in the older versions that have been fixed.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616

Third you likely need to do more manipulation of the file after using Get-Content before you can measure it.  If it's a CSV you may need to specify the specific column you want to manipulate.  If you provide more detail of what you are trying to do in a general sense, it'd be easier to provide more targeted feedback.